# Seg Fault, malloc char pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, typedef

I keep getting a segmentation fault and i know its from the char pointer. But I cant figure out why?

```
Whiskey* createWhiskey(int a, double p, char* n){

    Whiskey* whiskey = malloc(sizeof(Whiskey));
    whiskey->age = a;
    whiskey->proof = p;
    whiskey->name = malloc((strlen(n)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(whiskey->name, n);
    return whiskey;
}
int main(){

    Whiskey* burbon;
    burbon = createWhiskey(12, 90.0, "MakersMark");

    free(burbon);

    return 0;
}
```

In a comment from Alex (see below) the following information is added:

```
typedef struct{ int age; double proof; char* name; }Whiskey;
```

Comment: can you show us the `Whiskey` structure definition.

Comment: Please update whole code

Comment: Assuming the data struct is "the obvious", then apart from not null checking the malloc results it looks ok. Have you tried a debugger or prints to narrow down the crash location?

Comment: When you post code please make sure you post complete with the definition and declaration .

Comment: I assume you included `<string.h>` right?  And `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: BTW it's "bourbon", not "burbon".

Comment: I love Maker's Mark. Oh, and your code segment here compiles fine, assuming the struct definition (int, double, char *) I came up with is correct. You need to post all relevant code.

Comment: Yes I have all the needed include statements. Here is the declaration. 
typedef struct{
    int age;
    double proof;
    char* name;
}Whiskey;
It looks fine and from your comments it seems like everything should work smoothly but it just outputs seg fault. Ive tried this code with taking out the char* and creating with just the age and proof and it will run fine so I know its a problem with the char*

Comment: Assuming `malloc` is properly declared (via `<stdlib.h>`), and assuming `strcpy` is properly declared (via `<string.h>`), I can't see why this wouldn't work.  I tried it on my computer, along with the definition of `Whiskey` given in the comment, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Alex - don't add code in a comment. Edit the question instead. Don't you miss a `free( burbon->name);` ? Besides that the code is fine so your problem is not what you think it is.

Comment: I would suggest just to use `strdup` for duplicating the parameter 'n'. Nevertheless you should first free burbon->name(like @4386427 already mentioned) and then free the burbon pointer.

Comment: I just double checked the program by running it on my ubuntu computer and it ran fine just like you said. So I am truly lost now because I was using a raspberry pi before to run it and don't think there's a difference since I am using gcc to compile on both. Thank you for your help though. now I know that the program is fine.

Comment: @Alex - I think you should add some check to your code: 1) Does `malloc` return a null pointer. 2) Check `strlen(n)` before calling `malloc`

Comment: Why didn't you show a complete program?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments the program shown is fine.

However, you should add some checks to avoid problems. Something like:

```
typedef struct{ int age; double proof; char* name; } Whiskey;

Whiskey* createWhiskey(int a, double p, char* n){
    Whiskey* whiskey = malloc(sizeof(Whiskey));
    if (whiskey) 
    {
        whiskey->age = a;
        whiskey->proof = p;
        if (strlen(n) > SOME_MAXIMUM)
        {
            free(whiskey);
            printf("Some error... maybe\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        whiskey->name = malloc((strlen(n)+1) * sizeof(char));
        if (whiskey->name)
        {
            strcpy(whiskey->name, n);
        }
        else
        {
            free(whiskey);
            printf("Some error... \n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return whiskey;
}

int main(){

    Whiskey* burbon;
    burbon = createWhiskey(12, 90.0, "MakersMark");
    if (!burbon)
    {
        printf("Some error... \n");
    }    

    // code....

    if (burbon)
    {
        free( burbon->name);
        free(burbon);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope definition of your Whiskey structure is fine. Following code works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Whisk {
        int age;
        double proof;
        char *name;
} Whiskey;
Whiskey* createWhiskey(int a, double p, char* n){

    Whiskey* whiskey = malloc(sizeof(Whiskey));
    whiskey->age = a;
    whiskey->proof = p;
    whiskey->name = malloc((strlen(n)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(whiskey->name, n);
    return whiskey;
}

int main(){

    Whiskey* burbon;
    burbon = createWhiskey(12, 90.0, "MakersMark");
    if (!burbon)
    {
        printf("Some error... \n");
    }

    // code....

    if (burbon)
    {
        free( burbon->name);
        free(burbon);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs appropriate error checking
3. does not seg fault when run
4. performs the desired function
5. cleans up properly by passing both allocated memory pointers to `free()`
6. uses meaningful names for the passed parameters

the code:

```
#include <string.h>  // malloc()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdio.h>   // perror()

typedef struct
{
    int age;
    double proof;
    char* name;
} Whiskey;

Whiskey* createWhiskey(int age, double proof, char* name)
{

    Whiskey* whiskey = NULL;
    if( NULL == (whiskey = malloc(sizeof(Whiskey)) ) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for Whiskey failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    whiskey->age = age;
    whiskey->proof = proof;
    whiskey->name = NULL;

    if( NULL == (whiskey->name = malloc( strlen(name)+1) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for name field failed" );
        free( whiskey );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    strcpy(whiskey->name, name);
    return whiskey;
} // end function: createWhiskey


int main( void )
{

    Whiskey* burbon;
    burbon = createWhiskey(12, 90.0, "MakersMark");

    free( burbon->name );
    free( burbon );

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```